# How to get anything else that a string with ChoiceField in django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

I created a form with some ChoiceField inside. My probleme is that I always get a string even if the value of my ChoiceField is an integer or an array. In my view I try to handle the data of the form and get something like that :

```
        formTemplate = QcmForm(request.POST)
        if(formTemplate.is_valid()):
             rep1 = formTemplate.cleaned_data['Q1']
             print("REPONSE", rep1)
             print("::", type(rep1))
```

And this is what I get

REPONSE :  [('L', 1)]
::  <class 'str'>

So Here is how I defined my form and a second try I did with TypeChoiceField which wasn't sucessful :

```
Q1_TITLE = "intitule of question"
Q2_CHOICES = (
    ([("L", 1)], "some item"),
    ([("W", 0.5)], "other item")
)

class QcmForm(forms.Form):
    Q1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices = Q1_CHOICES, label=Q1_TITLE, initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```

So if I choose "some item" I get in my print a string instead of a list or a tuple.

Next Try : I changeed with TypeChoiceField

```
class QcmForm(forms.Form):
    Q1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=list, choices = Q1_CHOICES, label=Q1_TITLE, initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```

And here the result is worst, it consider my reponse as a list of character instead of a list of tuple.

REPONSE :  ['[', '(', "'", 'L', "'", ',', ' ', '1', ')', ']']
::  <class 'list'>

Thank you for reading and if you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TypedChoiceField` is indeed the way to go. However, the `coerce` argument is a function that takes a string as argument (the raw content of the POST data), and returns it as you want it.

Thus, when you pass `coerce=list`, it will return `list("[('L', 1)]")`, `"[('L', 1)]"` being the string representation of your initial list. Yet, calling `list()` on a string, returns a list of characters, which is not what you want.

If you want to get back your list from its string representation, you will have to write a function that converts a string representation of a list into an actual list. Writing such parsing function is quite hard and not really efficient. Of course, a straightforward way to convert a string representation of a list to an actual list would be to use `coerce=eval`, but this is a severe security issue as anyone could just send random python code to run on your server instead of a list.

I would rather suggest to define a representation format that you can easily parse. For instance:

```py
Q1_TITLE = "intitule of question"
Q1_CHOICES = (
    ('L/1', "some item"),
    ('W/0.5', "other item")
)

def choice_parser(value):
   i, j = value.split('/', 1)
   return [(i, float(j))]

class QcmForm(forms.Form):
    Q1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=choice_parser, choices = Q1_CHOICES, label=Q1_TITLE, initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```